# Callback URL for OAuth 2.0 authentication in Firecamp

Tags: api, salesforce, rest

I'm new to Firecamp, was trying to hit Salesforce REST API using Firecamp and I'm not able to find any article related to the Callback URL, can someone please help ?

Like Callback URL for Postman is ".https://getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE0YM.png)

Comment: If you are trying to generate token, try `https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/callback` for sandbox

Comment: You can pass the same domain as callback URL in Firecamp which you're using in URLbar to fetch response.